# How to use a custom defined lock to a string value?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am unsure whether to use Mutex or Semaphore or some other facility.

Here is my scenario: In a multithreaded environment some event results into an image being written to disk. This image is generated in the event handler.

The issue is, that the event A causes an image A.png being written and event B an image called B.png.

If those events occur at the same time the images can be saved (although obviously the disk does not handle parallel writes very well) but it is a valid scenario.

But there are times when event A is fired multiple times. This is also valid but calling image.Save for the same file name leads to a Generic GDI error.

How can I lock the .Save(...) call with a facility without locking every thread (like using the lock keyword)

I thought about a handmade solution where the handler writes the filename into a lookup table and then writes the file. Other handlers would need to check the lookup and then do some Thread.Sleep or similar. But this does look like the naive approach to resource locking.

Is there a proper way for such custom locks that do lock around a "virtual" resource? (Virtual as it may not exist at the time of locking).

**Update and edit:**
The image generation performs some number crunching and is therefore wrapped in a Task. A typical scenario would be always creating multiple images at the same time to utilize the Thread.Pool. 
I know that a job queue would solve the issue but it would remove the parallel execution. If I would distribute the jobs to n-threads manually (which would mean writing my own pool, right?) I would still run into the problem that two threads could try to write the same file.

The event source is unreliable, therefore it might call the write operation multiple times with the same file but actually as long as one "image A" generation is either in work or not yet started the second, third or whatever event handling can be ignored.

Comment: Is each thread referencing the same Image, or a different Image?  Is the most recent event supposed to cause an overwrite of the previous file?

Comment: I've updated the question. Typically every thread should write different images based on event source data but as the event source is unreliable it may call the handler that spawns a Task with the same source data multiple times. While it is no problem to overwrite the image it just can't happen twice at the same time :)

Comment: Then as per my answer but have a seperate Queue for each filename that you intend to write. The only locking you ever need is around saving that particular filename to ensure that only one attempt can be made at any time. The rest of the workflow can be and will be fully multithreaded but all attempts to write the final file will require acquiring the lock for the filename-specific queue (or using a BlockingCollection, as suggested by Jim and Alexander below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `Queue<MyImageWriteTaskClass>.` 
Spawn a thread that checks if the queue is populated and if so, dequeues the queue's contents one by one, writing the images to disk, until the queue is empty, when the thread resumes waiting until a new item has been enqueued.
When the event is fired, simply enqueue a new `MyImageWriteTaskClass`.

Assuming you use a thread-safe queue, no other locking should be required than a single lock around around dequeuing and enqueuing. You might need to throttle your disk save operations if your hardware can't keep up, or if you have disk caching.

*Or* if you want to get fancy and use the latest and greatest tools, you could have a look into using IObservable and processing an Observable stream of Save events . This has the added benefit of greatly simplifying such quite fancy mechanisms as throttling.

Comment: +1: Yes, definitely create a queue of write requests and have a single thread process that queue. Trying to do it with locks is just a mess. I highly recommend using `BlockingCollection<T>` for the queue.

Comment: That is not what I want, I think. The image generation and writing is already wrapped in a Task as the generation is quite CPU bound. Using a queue would definitely work but it would make the entire process single threaded.

Answer (score 2):

In addintion to the Mark's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19121227/1166450):
You can use `BlockingCollection<T>` class, it implements producer-consumer pattern. See `ConsumingEnumerableDemo` class in *Examples* section of [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx).